# Migration details for DynamoDB v2 in AWS Java SDK?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Has anyone made the change to the new namespaces (`com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2`) and interfaces for DynamoDB in the AWS Java SDK 1.4.2 (and later)? The release of Local Secondary Indices apparently necessitated breaking changes as per [the 1.4.2 release notes](http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/Java/7912157505356585).

Has anyone found a guide detailing what changed and what needs to happen to migrate existing code? I am trying to decide when is best to make this change for an existing code base.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The new *dynamodbv2* namespace of DynamoDB introduces the following incompatible changes (in that they are not simply additive, and require code changes to switch to the new namespace):

- *HashKeyElement* and *RangeKeyElement* are replaced with a *Map<String, AttributeValue>*.  This includes the structures named *ExclusiveStartKey*, *LastEvaluatedKey*, and *Key*.  The main impact on the code with this change is that now in order to call *GetItem*, for example, your code needs to know the attribute names of the primary keys, and not just the primary key values.
- Query now uses a *KeyCondition* of type *Map<String, Condition>* to specify the full query, instead of having separate *HashKeyValue* and *RangeKeyCondition* fields.
- CreateTable input separates the attribute type definitions from the primary key definitions (and create/update/delete/describe responses match this)
- Consumed Capacity in responses is now a structure instead of a single number, and must be asked for in the request. In Batch operations, this is returned in a separate *ConsumedCapacity* structure, instead of alongside the results.

It is possible to migrate your code to the new Java API incrementally, if desired.  If you plan to add functionality to your code that queries Local Secondary Indexes, or creates tables with local secondary indexes, you will need to use the new API for that part of your code.

If you create a table with Local Secondary Indexes with the new API, you can still use your existing code in the *dynamodb* namespace to perform all of the existing operations on that table.  As an example, PutItem with the *dynamodb* namespace client will work against tables created using the *dynamodbv2* client, as well as the other way around.

Comment: Thanks for this. It's a good summary and includes some things that I didn't need for my specific migration.

Answer (score 9):

**DynamoDB AWS Java 1.4.1 => 1.4.2 (non-exhaustive) migration steps**

Well, I bit the bullet and did it. Here's my experience.

First, change the DynamoDB namespace:

- `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodb` => `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2`

The first thing you notice is there are types missing. The most major is Key is gone. Good riddance as it was too generic of a name.
It is now replaced with Map which makes sense as keys become a lot more malleable with [Local Secondary Indexes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html) (LSI).
Unfortunately, working with maps and generics in general sucks in Java (see **Bonus** at bottom).
Gone are the fluent interfaces of `withHashKeyElement` / `withRangeKeyElement`.

Next, very carefully find/replace the DynamoDB types which were replaced by generic collections:

- `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodb.model.Key` => `Map<String, AttributeValue>`
- `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodb.model.BatchResponse` => `List<Map<String, AttributeValue>>`
- `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodb.model.KeySchema` => `List<KeySchemaElement>`
- (Probably others, these were the few I directly referenced.)

Next, find everything that broke. This is a *very* manual process that requires knowing your code base and the SDK quite well.
Specifically, you must know your key schema very well as it's all strings from here on. Luckily in my situation, the first two tasks were about 90% of the changes:

- Find every `new Map<String, AttributeValue>`, it is an indication that `Key` was formerly there.
- `QueryRequest` merged `withHashKeyValue(AttributeValue)` `withRangeKeyCondition(Condition)` into the mega [`withKeyConditions(Map<String,Condition>)`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/QueryRequest.html#withKeyConditions(java.util.Map)) 
  This method is the core change for LSI lets you specify things other than hash/range. What it accepts is more restrictive than the interface, but this is logical when you consider DynamoDB only lets you query indexed attributes.
- `DynamoDBQueryExpression` became generic and changed its interface (not sure why).
- `KeySchemaElement` no longer needs `AttributeType`, but now needs `KeyType`

Finally, Compile and regression test your entire stack.

P.S. While I was performing all this, [version 1.4.4.1](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/commits/) was just released to Maven Central.

---

**Bonus**

Since Maps are the common solution to Java's lack of loosely typed classes, they are everywhere.
A little helper lib can really go a long way toward building these less verbosely.
Here are some bits of my helper:

```
public class MakeJavaSuckLess { // TODO: find a shorter class name
    public static final float MAX_LOAD_FACTOR = 1.0f;

    /**
     * Builds a mutable Map from an interlaced sequence of key-value pairs
     * where keys are strings and values are VType objects
     * @param pairs
     * @return
     */
    public static <VType> Map<String, VType> asMap(Object... pairs) {
        return mergeMaps(null, pairs);
    }

    /**
     * Builds a mutable Map from an interlaced sequence of key-value pairs
     * where keys are strings and values are VType objects
     * @param pairs
     * @return
     */
    public static <VType> Map<String, VType> mergeMaps(Map<String, VType> map, Object... pairs) {
        final int length = (pairs != null) ? pairs.length/2 : 0;
        if (map == null) {
            // max out the load factor since most of these don't change
            map = new HashMap<String, VType>(length, MAX_LOAD_FACTOR);
        }

        for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
            String key = asString(pairs[2*i]);
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            VType value = (VType)pairs[2*i+1];
            map.put(key, value);
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

Now creating your DynamoDB keys is slightly less ugly:

```
Map<String, AttributeValue> key = MakeJavaSuckLess.asMap("hashKey", new AttributeValue("hashVal"), "rangeKey", new AttributeValue("rangeVal"));
```

[Type erasure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Problems_with_type_erasure) in Java's generics makes this again uglier in places. You will sometimes need to explicitly specify `VType`:

```
new GetItemRequest().withKey(MakeJavaSuckLess.<AttributeValue>asMap("hashKey", new AttributeValue("hashVal"), "rangeKey", new AttributeValue("rangeVal")));
```

Comment: Inspired by this stackoverflow question and your map builder tip, I wrote a blog post about using Google Guava's Map Builders and a few other tips for [writing less code when using DynamoDB's Java SDK](https://java.awsblog.com/post/Tx2VOZ8V9I67LLD/Writing-less-code-when-using-the-AWS-SDK-for-Java).  I hope it helps!

Comment: Without this question and answer, migrating my code would have been a nightmare, thank you. Surprised Amazon broke so much in this change.