# Difference between DynamoDbAsyncClient and AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClient

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I need to use dynamo DB async operations and found two clients **DynamoDbAsyncClient** and **AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClient** for the same. Could anyone please tell me the difference and pros, cons of these two clients.

Answer (score 2):

AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClient is from the package dynamodbv2

DynamoDBAsyncClient is from the package dynamodb

There are couple threads talking about this already

[Migration details for DynamoDB v2 in AWS Java SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612365/migration-details-for-dynamodb-v2-in-aws-java-sdk)